# iPhone 4s search sometimes stays blank

Tags: iphone, search

Search page works very well except when it doesn't work at all. In those cases it just stays blank. What's the fix for that?

Comment: I have the same problem and would like to know if there is a fix or an update to fix this problem. Happing on my iPhone 4s and my wife's as well.

Comment: mine ocasionally stops functioning and I have been able to get it started again by shutting down and restarting the phone, and typing in just the first letter for the search. Also worked when I pressed and depressed the shift button on the keyboard before typing in the first letter. Weird, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me too. A temporary "fix" is to turn off mail search in Spotlight. (Found on the [Apple Discussion Board](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16954362?tstart=0#16954362?tstart=0.))

Comment: Do you know if mail is the cause, or just making any arbitrary change to the rules will jumpstart the stuck process?